# ¿Por qué mi página es más ancha de lo normal?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy empezando a aprender diseño web (html/css).

Venía practicando con una página web varias horas, y noté que el ancho de la página sobresale un poco por lo que crea un scroll horizontal, estuve buscando, observando y borrando ciertas partes para saber dónde estaba el problema y no soy capaz de encontrarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he usado JS y estoy usando **bootstrap.min.css 5.1.0**.

Empecé haciendo todo lo más normal, pero en un momento me percaté que había un *scroll* y desde ahí estuve intentando normalizarlo pero no sé de dónde sale.

> **Edit:** intenté borrar cada `div` y cada etiqueta incluyendo en css para ver cuál era el problema y no lo encontré, algo se me debe haber pasado pero ni idea.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body {
    background-image:url(img/bkg.png);
    background-size: cover;
}

/*-------- HEADER------- */
#header {
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgba(85, 125, 177,0.5);
    color:white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100px;
}
#logo h1 {
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

    font-size: 70px;
}
#redes {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;

}
#redes img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

/*-------- NAVBAR ------- */

#navbar {
width: 100%;
background-color: rgb(85, 125, 177);
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.menu li {
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.menu li a {
    width: 120px;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

}
.menu li #ini {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.3);
    transition: 0.4s;

}
.menu li a:active{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


@media(max-width:575px) {
  
    .menu li a {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 2px;
    }
    .menu ul{
        flex-direction: column;
     }
    .menu li {
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    }
}
/*-------- CONTENIDO ------- */
.contenido {
    margin: 70px;
}
.contenido h3 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.contenido p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: justify;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: bold;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 5px;   
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
 #b {
 text-align: center;
}
#c {
    text-align: right;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" media="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>

    <div class="row" id="header"> 
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 ">
        </div>


        <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12"> 
            <div id="logo"><h1>MI PAGINA </h1></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"> 
            <div id="redes">
                <img src="img/fb.png">
                <img src="img/ig.png">
                <img src="img/tw.png">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>



    <div class="row">           
            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 " id="navbar">

                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#" id="ini">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Sobre Mi</a></li>

                    </ul>


                </nav>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="contenido">
                    <i><h3 id="a">
                        DISEÑO WEB
                    </h3>
                    <h3 id="b">
                        HTML & CSS
                    </h3>
                    <h3 id="c">
                        TEMPLATES
                    </h3></i>

                    <p>Bienvenidos, esta es mi primera pagina web profesional creada desde cero con html y css.
                        Voy a intentar ir publicando mis avances y nuevos proyectos a medida del tiempo.
                        Ahora mismo estoy recien empezando con CSS/BOOTSTRAP luego ire aprendiendo algo de PHP. <br>
                        Esta pagina la realize 3 veces desde cero por problemas al maquetarla, esta ultima vez la armé en 3-4hs aproximadamente
                        y consegui un resultado que me convencio.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="perfil"
                 >asd
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>


    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en los elementos `.row` que estás usando. Estos, entre otras reglas **CSS** tienen estas:

```
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
```

Esto rompe con el layout de la Web ocasionando que desborde. Este comportamiento de los `.row` es normal, sirve para para que los `.col` de dentro de un `.row` se comporten debidamente. Lo que tienes que hacer es que en tu **HTML** nunca exista un `.row` que no tenga como ancestro un `.container` o un `.container-fluid`. También tienes que evitar tener un `.col` que no tenga como ancestro un `.row` porque ocasionarías también un descuadre.

En mi solución envolví todo el **HTML** que tienes en tu `<body>` en un `.container-fluid`.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body {
    background-image:url(img/bkg.png);
    background-size: cover;
}

/*-------- HEADER------- */
#header {
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgba(85, 125, 177,0.5);
    color:white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100px;
}
#logo h1 {
    text-shadow: 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

    font-size: 70px;
}
#redes {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;

}
#redes img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

/*-------- NAVBAR ------- */

#navbar {
width: 100%;
background-color: rgb(85, 125, 177);
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.menu li {
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.menu li a {
    width: 120px;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

}
.menu li #ini {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.3);
    transition: 0.4s;

}
.menu li a:active{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


@media(max-width:575px) {
  
    .menu li a {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 2px;
    }
    .menu ul{
        flex-direction: column;
     }
    .menu li {
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    }
}
/*-------- CONTENIDO ------- */
.contenido {
    margin: 70px;
}
.contenido h3 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.contenido p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: justify;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: bold;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 5px;   
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
 #b {
 text-align: center;
}
#c {
    text-align: right;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" media="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="header"> 
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 ">
        </div>


        <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12"> 
            <div id="logo"><h1>MI PAGINA </h1></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"> 
            <div id="redes">
                <img src="img/fb.png">
                <img src="img/ig.png">
                <img src="img/tw.png">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>



    <div class="row">           
            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 " id="navbar">

                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#" id="ini">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Sobre Mi</a></li>

                    </ul>


                </nav>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="contenido">
                    <i><h3 id="a">
                        DISEÑO WEB
                    </h3>
                    <h3 id="b">
                        HTML & CSS
                    </h3>
                    <h3 id="c">
                        TEMPLATES
                    </h3></i>

                    <p>Bienvenidos, esta es mi primera pagina web profesional creada desde cero con html y css.
                        Voy a intentar ir publicando mis avances y nuevos proyectos a medida del tiempo.
                        Ahora mismo estoy recien empezando con CSS/BOOTSTRAP luego ire aprendiendo algo de PHP. <br>
                        Esta pagina la realize 3 veces desde cero por problemas al maquetarla, esta ultima vez la armé en 3-4hs aproximadamente
                        y consegui un resultado que me convencio.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="perfil"
                 >asd
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Revise tu código y no le encontré nada raro; el escroll que observas lo genera automáticamente el navegador cuando el área de visualización es mas pequeña que el documento.

```
Nota: agrega un `<div class="container"></div>` antes del row.
```

[image: captura de pantalla]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar un **width:100vw** a todo el body, forzando a que el ancho de la página sea estrictamente el de cualquier pantalla que vea el sitio web, tal que así.

```
    body {
        background-image:url(img/bkg.png);
        background-size: cover;
        width:100vw;
       }
```

Comment: Mala idea, esto repercute negativamente la vista en demás pantallas, además que es muy global.